# Curve line tracking

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm working on project in my university and i have a problem. The goal is to create algorithm that can track curves in plot images and create a lists of Point(x,y) with predefined accuracy/step that describes the curves.

The number of curves on each image >=1 and width >=1 pixel. Curves may have multiple intersections and colors. They also can have the same color.

The example of what i want to do:

[image]

Dots are points that i need to extract. The scanning area must be picked by user(no axis or text in scaning area). I found some interesting [here](http://twiki.mssl.ucl.ac.uk/twiki/bin/viewfile/SDO/LoopRecognition?rev=1.1;filename=MSthesis.pdf), but i don't feel that i'm strong in mathematics. I need something easier.

Comment: Dmitri: The paper you cited is very good. If you are not able to follow the math there, perhaps you should ask for existent languages/libraries to do that. In your question, although not clearly stated, seems you're looking for an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the predefined steps are on the horizontal axis, say x-axis, and since the stepsize is given, you could start at the most left pixel of the user selected area. For any specific value of x, you process the image from the lower bound upwards, and detect the colors. Each of these colors will have a distribution(i.e. it isn't just on one pixel for a given x), and I recommend taking the average of this distribution.
You should of course repeat this until the next step in the x-direction would fall outside of the user selected area. Now you only have to tweak the mechanism for color detecting, namely to allow for a slight range of colors, instead of pure red of blue etc, but that's an entire different (though not as hard) problem.

One more thing, it could be that at the given value of x two graphs overlap, and one might not be visible. In that case you could increment x a bit and try again, and if you detect it at that x, you can reason easily behind which other graph it is at the previous x.

Good luck

Comment: what if all lines are black? :(

Comment: Ok, suppose two graps for a value of x aren't overlapping, this algorithm can be used. Also the overlapping part can be done with the suggestion I made at the end. I suppose the only problem left is determining if two graphs join and seperate further on, which 'incoming' branch belongs to which 'outgoing' branch?

In your example it is sufficient to say the lower incoming branch will be the upper outgoing branch and vice versa. There might indeed be rare cases where this isn't true. But I don't recommend a solution like the link you gave, since that is overcomplicated for your situation.